# Seneca-web timeout configuration

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, seneca

First of all I would like to say that I am new in senecajs.

I am testing this configuration.

I have configured Senecjs microservice running on port 9007, which is running and handling request correctly. When I request this service directly I receive response after cca 10s (it is request for oracle db data).

But when I request for same data but through the Hapi + Seneca-web I receive this error: **"statusCode":504,"error":"Gateway Time-out"**

```
["client","invalid_origin",{"port":9007,"pin":"mc:bankgtw","pg":"mc:bankgtw","type":"web","id":"pg:mc:bankgtw,pin:mc:bankgtw,port:9007","role":"transport","hook":"client","plugin$":{"name":"client$"},"fatal$":true,"meta$":{"mi":"wbn8u45tb7uh","tx":"o3f8eyia3f4n","id":"wbn8u45tb7uh/o3f8eyia3f4n","pattern":"hook:client,role:transport,type:web","action":"(q1yytemztu3k)","plugin_name":"transport","plugin_tag":"-","prior":{"chain":[],"entry":true,"depth":0},"start":1487199713842,"sync":true},"tx$":"o3f8eyia3f4n","host":"0.0.0.0","path":"/act","protocol":"http","timeout":5555,"max_listen_attempts":11,"attempt_delay":222,"serverOptions":{}},{"kind":"res","res":null,"error":{"isBoom":true,"isServer":true,"output":{"statusCode":504,"payload":{**"statusCode":504,"error":"Gateway Time-out**","message":"Client request timeout"},"headers":{}}},"sync":true,"time":{"client_recv":1487199799177}}]
```

A few seconds before microservice return data.

And this is my configuration:

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Seneca = require('seneca');
const SenecaWeb = require('seneca-web');

const config = {
  adapter: require('seneca-web-adapter-hapi'),
  context: (() => {
    const server = new Hapi.Server();
    server.connection({
      port: 3001,
      routes: {
            cors: true,
            payload:{timeout:60000},
            timeout:{server: 60000, socket:90000}
        }
    });

    server.route({
      path: '/routes',
      method: 'get',
      handler: (request, reply) => {
        const routes = server.table()[0].table.map(route => {
          return {
            path: route.path,
            method: route.method.toUpperCase(),
            description: route.settings.description,
            tags: route.settings.tags,
            vhost: route.settings.vhost,
            cors: route.settings.cors,
            jsonp: route.settings.jsonp,
            server: server.info
          }
        })
        reply(routes)
      }
    });

    return server;
  })()
};

const seneca = Seneca({timeout: 99999})
  .use(SenecaWeb, config)
  .use(require('./hapi_api.js'))
  .client({ port:9007,  pin:'mc:bankgtw' })
  .ready(() => {
    const server = seneca.export('web/context')();
    server.start(() => {
      server.log('server started on: ' + server.info.uri);
    });
  });
```

What I am doing wrong or what timeout is causing this?

Comment: Probably somewhere a callback is not being invoked.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue, fixed it, but its **VERY BAD PRACTICE.**

Go to 'transport.js' at seneca-transport folder.
You will see 'timeout: 5555'
Go ahead and change that to whatever you need.

I'm not sure why this is not getting USER defaults.
To the best of my knowledge, this is referring to client timeout. make sure you still use server timeout.